# Experiment to calculate rPi instructions per second

Tags: assembly, raspberry-pi, instructions

In an online course I'm taking, I am given the task of experimenting to determine the amount of instructions per second that the Raspberry Pi executes by blinking an LED with the code below.
In my assessment, a single outer loop iterates through 16,616,072 times (which is double 0x7e0000), since we have two delay inner loops. I used a timer to estimate that it takes 1.55 seconds for a single outer loop (a single LED blink cycle). In this time, the RPI executes approximately the same amount of instructions as iterations (the non-inner loop instructions are insignificant in number). Therefore, 16,616,072/1.55 = 10,654,885 instructions per second.

I counted `subs r2, #1` as the main instruction being executed. I did not count `bne wait1`. Is that considered an instruction?

Am I estimating the instructions per second accurately?

```
.equ DELAY, 0x7e0000

// configure GPIO 20 for output
ldr r0, FSEL2
mov r1, #1
str r1, [r0]

// set bit 20
mov r1, #(1<<20)

loop: 

// set GPIO 20 high
ldr r0, SET0
str r1, [r0] 

// delay
mov r2, #DELAY
wait1:
    subs r2, #1
    bne wait1

// set GPIO 20 low
ldr r0, CLR0
str r1, [r0] 

// delay
mov r2, #DELAY
wait2:
    subs r2, #1
    bne wait2

b loop

FSEL0: .word 0x20200000
FSEL1: .word 0x20200004
FSEL2: .word 0x20200008
SET0:  .word 0x2020001C
SET1:  .word 0x20200020
CLR0:  .word 0x20200028
CLR1:  .word 0x2020002C
```

Comment: `Am I estimating the instructions per second accurately?`, no where close imo

Comment: any pointers to put me in the right direction?

Comment: All instructions are instructions, including branches.  Also note that IPC (instructions per clock) depends on *which* instructions are going through the pipeline.  A CPU that can run 4 instructions per clock can probably still only run 1 taken branch per clock, so a 2-instruction loop would only run 2 IPC at best, with no branch mispredicts.  GPIO loads/stores will be *very* slow compare to normal instructions that don't go off-core.  But if you're measuring IPC (or I per second) for this specific workload, then yeah just count total instructions / total time.

Comment: that would include `bne wait1`, but would it include `wait1:` as well or is that only cycled through once at the entrance to the inner loop?

Comment: @brunshte `wait1:` is a label, not an instruction.  Labels do not exist at runtime and do not consume runtime.